# 2 IntentServices accessing the same data on file system.. safe?

Tags: java, android

I'm relatively sure with this, but I need your opinion. I have two IntentServices on Android, both have access to the application's private file system.

The filesystem works like a queue - the first IntentService only performs write operations, that means it does nothing other than creating new files. The second IntentService only reads and deletes files from the application's filesystem.. similar to the "producer/consumer" principle.

In my opinion, there is no need to do any syncing or locking operations, even if both services have their own threads. I am correct here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syncing  or locking is needed only when different threads are working on the same file reading or writing. As far as your case is concerned, if you have  a queue of files and your threads are acting on different ends of queue there's no need of syncing the operation in that case.